# CAS-6-Forgot username unable to sent user name in mail

Tags: email, cas

I am new in CAS-6 and trying to send user name in mail, I created "forgot.password.gtemplat" file for email.
In template I am trying to get username from attribute using this syntax "**<%=principal.attributes.username %>"**, **"<%=email %>"**
value of email is email address entered by user this returns proper value but value of **<%=principal.attributes.username %>** " is printing null, I didn't understand why, In console it says "None of the principal resolvers in the chain were able to produce a principal".
For attribute resolution I am calling rest API.

Comment: Had the same problem. I got around it by changing the SendForgotUsernameInstructionsAction.java in the overlay but that is not the right way of doing it. It could not set the username because a principal was not getting resolved, so I jumped that resolver and just set the username I got from the query directly. Let me know if I should make a separate answer for this, but beware that my solution is not recommended by CAS!